# HiveQL query from the HBase

Tags: hbase, hive

I create a external table in Hive which points to a table in HBase, select all the contents from column family 'animal', and I do SELECT * FROM this_table in hive, it shows me like this:

```
1   {"cat":"10"}
2   {"tiger":"20"}
3   {"dog":"15"}
4   {"bear":"10"}
```

"cat" is the identifier name under the 'animal' and '10' is the value.

Now I want to query the value of 'cat', how could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

What does the schema of your hive and hbase table look like. You need to map hive columns with  hbase ColumnFamily:ColumnQualifier.

While creating external table you can specify column mappings like this -

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hive_table (cat String)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = "animal:cat")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "hbase_table");
```